# AngularJS data not showing up on page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a little trouble with this AngularJS page, it is not showing the data that it should.

I just recently started to work with angular, so a pointer, or an advise is welcomed.

Here is the Factory, and the Controller:

```
var app = angular.module('mpDataApp', [])
.controller('MpMapController', MpMapController)
.factory('GetMpData', GetMpData)

function GetMpData($http) {
    var data = [];
    return {
        getData: function () {
            return $http.get('MpWatch/GetMpData').success(function (data, status, header, config) {
            }).then(function (results) {
                data = ParseMpResults(results.data.d);
                return data;
            })
        },
    };
}

function MpMapController(GetMpData) {
    GetMpData.getData().then(function (data) {
        angular.extend(this, {
            mpData: data,
        });
    });
};
```

And here is the markup:

```
//ng-app declared higher in the markup    
<div>
        <div ng-controller="MpMapController as mp">
            <ul >
                <li>
                    Number of records: {{mp.mpData.length}}
                </li>
                <li ng-repeat="mps in mp.mpData" >
                    <p>{{mps.deviceId}}</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the problem is, during debug a can see that "mpData" has the correct data as what it should be showing. But the page is not displaying it, and no errors displayed. In Visual Studio, i can hover over "mpData" in the markup and it shows the data is present.

[image: Debug Capture]

Yet it's not displayed on the page.
Thanks in advance for any help, advise, or a pointer.

Peter

**Update:**

Here is what did the trick, thank you for all the answers, it helped me get it right.

```
function GetMpData($http) {
    return {
        getData: function () {
            return $http.get('/MpWatch/GetMpData')
                  .then(function (response) {
                      return {
                          data: ParseMpResults(response.data.d),
                      }
                  });
        },
    };
};

function MpMapController(GetMpData) {
    var mp = this;
    var self = this;
    GetMpData.getData().then(function (mpResults) {
        angular.extend(self, {
            mpData: mpResults.data,
        })
    });
};
```

Data show on the page now properly.

Comment: The approach looks fine. When you inspect the elements in your browser dev tools what do you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module('mpDataApp', [])
  .controller('MpMapController', MpMapController)
  .factory('GetMpData', GetMpData)

function GetMpData($http) {
  var data = [];
  return {
    getData: function() {
      return $http.get('MpWatch/GetMpData');
    },
  };
}

function MpMapController(GetMpData) {
  var mp = this;
  mp.mpData = [];
  GetMpData.getData().then(function(data) {
    mp.mpData = data

  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="mpDataApp">
  <div ng-controller="MpMapController as mp">
    <ul>
      <li>
        Number of records: {{mp.mpData.length}}
      </li>
      <li ng-repeat="mps in mp.mpData">
        <p>{{mps.deviceId}}</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the code was speaking for itself, and it has fixed the issue. The data now showing on the page. I just don't understand why it did not work with "angular.extend()"  and it works if i assign it to a scope variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below one. I have changed your service to return the `promise` since the syntax you had is wrong.

You should have the `ParseMpResults` method at your controller.

```
function GetMpData($http) {
    var data = [];
    return {
        getData: function () {
            return $http.get('MpWatch/GetMpData');
        },
    };
}

function MpMapController(GetMpData) {
    GetMpData.getData().then(function (results) {
        angular.extend(this, {
            mpData: ParseMpResults(results.data.d),
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually **the problem is that when your factory called, it is not waiting till response come and then assign to myData**, and compiler continues their execution to moving on view at that time that variable myData will blank and **after response come from server you can see the data inside that** variable but not at that time when views load it.

***So the best practice is that you have to define promises at there in you factory or services.***

so just return http call like this from factory.

```
 return $http.get('MpWatch/GetMpData');
```

and utilize promises to wait till response come from server and you can poppulate data inside views properly

Comment: Exact code is available in foram's code snippet what i was trying to saying is :)